# Swift array of dictionary , how to check any one element has greater than "one" value

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

```
var abc: [[String: Int ]] = 
[["a", 0, "b": 0, "c" : 1]]
```

In the above example, I need a logic where I will check whether the array of dictionary has any element(value) which is greater than 1.

In my project I am navigating user to the next screen, if the array of dictionary contains at least one element which is greater than 1.

Comment: What have you tried and what specific issues are you running into?

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in your code example, but you can find the value with

```
func ifContains(arr: [[String: Int ]], value: Int) -> Bool {
    for dict in arr {
        return dict.values.filter { $0 > 1 }.count > 0
    }
    
    return false
}

print(ifContains(arr: abc, value: 1))
```

Comment: This will unnecessarily iterate the whole collection even if it finds it at the first element

Comment: If not found in first array, it will be return false, no? Test it with `[["a": 0, "b": 0, "c" : 0], ["a": 2, "b": 3, "c" : 4]]`, you'll see. Also, `value` parameter is unused. Prefers isEmpty of `count` test maybe? And since you use filter, if the subarray if big, you'll iterate over it entirely.

Comment: `for val in dict.values where val > value { true }`

Comment: Btw you are not using the value property of your method

Comment: One more what if the declaration is like  var product = [[product]]()   and product is structure like struct product { price : Int = 0} then how to use above given logics ..help asap

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
let containsNonZeroValue = array.contains(where: { aSubDict in
    return aSubDict.contains { (key: String, value: Int) -> Bool in
        return value > 1
    }
})
```

We check the different aSubDict if they contains a dictionary value superior to 1.

We could have used `filter()`, `map()`, `flatMap()`, etc, but `contains()` has the advantage of stopping once a value has been found. So if you have a big array, and 2 at the 1 index, it won't iterate over the rest of the array.

In a more concatenated way if you know how to use closures and their arguments:

```
let containsNonZeroValue = array.contains(where: { $0.contains { $0.value > 1 } })
```

As suggested by [@Leo Dabus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2303865/leo-dabus) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63156109/swift-array-of-dictionary-how-to-check-any-one-element-has-greater-than-one/63156413#comment111682829_63156413), instead of iterating all the values of the sub dictionary, we can get all the values (aSubDict.values), and check if one of them respects the constraint.

```
let containsNonZeroValue = array.contains(where: { aSubDict in
    return aSubDict.values.contains(where: { $0 > 1 })
})
```

In the shorter way:

```
let containsNonZeroValue = array.contains(where: { $0.values.contains(where: { $0 > 1 }) })
```

Comment: You can check only the values property of the dictionary `contains{$0.values.contains{$0 > 1}}`